# Execute random command

Tags: bash, random

I want my bash script to execute random command of given below.
For example

```
[mysterious command] ("command1", "command2", "command3")
```

Comment: Do you want it really random, or just pseudo-random?

Comment: random i think, but can you write 2 please?

Comment: This reminds me of https://github.com/timofurrer/russian-roulette/blob/master/russian-roulette

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel BSD `rm` saves the day: `rm: illegal option -- -`  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should accomplish what you're looking for.

```
COMMANDS=("command1" "command2" "command3")
$(shuf -n1 -e "${COMMANDS[@]}")
```

Takes the array and uses `shuf` to generate a random command.

UPDATE: Changed shuf command per @steeldriver

Comment: can i add more commands than 3?

Comment: Yeah, I had a typo in the commands, You should be able to put as many as you want, the index is based off the length of the array.

Comment: If your `shuf` has the `-e` option, you can skip the indexing and just do `$(shuf -n1 -e "${commands[@]}")`

Comment: @steeldriver brilliant. Learn something new every day, updating my answer.

Answer (score 12):

Put your commands in an array.

```
cmds=( "cmd1" "cmd2" "cmd3" )
```

`$RANDOM` is a random number and `${#cmds[@]}` evaluates to the length of your array (3 in this example).  `$(( RANDOM % ${#cmds[@]} ))` will be a random number between 0 and one less than the length of the array `cmds`, i.e. 0, 1, or 2.

```
i=$(( RANDOM % ${#cmds[@]} ))
```

Doing the following would pick the string out of `$cmds` corresponding to the index `$i` and execute it as a command.

```
${cmds[i]}
```

or all in one go (which looks a bit horrible):

```
${cmds[RANDOM % ${#cmds[@]}]}
```