# How can i store commands as a variables and execute them randomly in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, variable, command, random

How can i store commands as a variables and execute them randomly in bash?

```
command1="
   convert -size 2000x1000 xc:none -gravity center \
    -stroke yellow -pointsize 50 -font Courier-BoldOblique -strokewidth 3 -annotate +100+100 "${caption}" \
    -blur 0x25 -level 0%,50% \
    -fill white -stroke none -annotate +100+100 "${caption}" \
    in.jpeg  +swap -gravity center -geometry +0-3 \
    -composite  out.jpeg
"
command2="
   convert -size 2000x1000 xc:none -gravity center \
    -fill white -pointsize 50 -stroke none -annotate +100+100 "${caption}" -channel alpha -evaluate multiply 0.35 -trim +repage \
    in.jpeg  +swap -gravity center -geometry +0-3 \
    -composite  out.jpeg
"
```

What have i tried

```
COMMANDS=("command1" "command2")
$(eval $(shuf -n1 -e "${COMMANDS[@]}"))
```

Desired output is to randomly run any of the two convert commands.
How can i get the desired result and where are the things going wrong ??

I have taken hints from -

[execute-random-command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/301315/execute-random-command)

[how-to-store-a-command-in-a-variable-in-a-shell-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615717/how-to-store-a-command-in-a-variable-in-a-shell-script)

Thanks in advance for help !!

Comment: Any reason why you can't turn those commands into functions? Then you could do just `"$(shuf -n1 -e command1 command2)"`.

Comment: Two reasons - first they are long and i have many other commands already written so changing each will be just a cumbersome task(these are just examples)

Comment: randomly or on-demand?

Comment: That being said, `C=("$command1" "$command2"); eval "$(shuf -n1 -e "${C[@]}")"` would probably work in your case. Notice the extra `$`s and the extra `"`s.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor  run them randomly

Comment: I note that the functions are not very random: the same command with one or two parameters changed. It will probably be easier to randomly change the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Use a function.

```
command1(){ 
   convert -size 2000x1000 xc:none -gravity center \
    -stroke yellow -pointsize 50 -font Courier-BoldOblique -strokewidth 3 -annotate +100+100 "${caption}" \
    -blur 0x25 -level 0%,50% \
    -fill white -stroke none -annotate +100+100 "${caption}" \
    in.jpeg  +swap -gravity center -geometry +0-3 \
    -composite  out.jpeg
}

command2() {
   convert -size 2000x1000 xc:none -gravity center \
    -fill white -pointsize 50 -stroke none -annotate +100+100 "${caption}" -channel alpha -evaluate multiply 0.35 -trim +repage \
    in.jpeg  +swap -gravity center -geometry +0-3 \
    -composite  out.jpeg
}
```

See why [Why variables fail when trying to run a command](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 3):

First, this won't work the moment you have whitespace or literal glob characters in the arguments:

```
command1="convert ... -fill white -stroke none -annotate +100+100 "${caption}" ...
```

Note how even the syntax highlighting shows that the `${caption}` part is *not* quoted. Quotes don't work inside quotes, i.e. quotes expanded from a parameter are literal, they don't quote again.

See:

- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373)
- [BashFAQ 050 - "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373)

Two better options are to store the commands in separate functions, or separate arrays. Sadly, you'll have to come with names for them, you can't have a (numbered) array of functions or an array of arrays.

Then, assuming you have functions or arrays called `cmd1` and `cmd2`, choose one just like you did there, and if you used functions, just run it:

```
commands=(cmd1 cmd2)
chosen=$(shuf -n1 -e "${commands[@]}")
"$chosen" args...
```

or if you used an array, you'll have to use a name ref to access it:

```
commands=(cmd1 cmd2)
declare -n chosen=$(shuf -n1 -e "${commands[@]}")
"${chosen[@]}" args...
```